# Codeigniter flashdata issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Codeigniter flash data issue**
I am not getting session flashdata value. I checked the session there flash data is created as old. Why this happens and how can i correct the issue.

my sessiona:

```
3:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:11:"cp";s:5:"l";s:14:"flash:old:fvalue";s:32:"41f666‌​04a0bec1c089d84023d3708d1d";}.
```

here flash data is marked as old. i created flash data in view this is my code `$this->session->set_flashdata('fvalue', '41f66604a0bec1c089d84023d3708d1d');`

Comment: Please do post your codes in your question.

Comment: Create the flash data in controller and then redirect the page. On view  I am not sure it will use without one redirection.

Answer (score 1):

To add flashdata:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('stack', 'overflow');
```

You can use on view with this code:

```
$this->session->flashdata('stack');
```

Be sure your web page shouldn't redirect one more times. If your redirection counts is more than one, you need to use:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('stack');
```

Comment: Its not working. please check my sessiona:   3:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:11:"cp";s:5:"l";s:14:"flash:old:fvalue";s:32:"41f66604a0bec1c089d84023d3708d1d";}.   here flash data is marked as old.            i created flash data in view this is my code  $this->session->set_flashdata('fvalue', '41f66604a0bec1c089d84023d3708d1d');

Comment: You can not set flash data on the view.

Answer (score 0):

To use Session class, In `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Setting Flash data

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');//$this->session->set_flashdata('name', 'Rakesh');
```

**after set flash data redirect to method** using

```
redirect('controller/method_name');
```

Then in view (to show/this will execute when `name` is set only)

```
<?php 
    if($this->session->flashdata('name') != '')
    {
        ?> 
        <div class="success">
        <?php $this->session->flashdata('name'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

To Destroy Session

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

[Codeigniter Flashdata](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)

Comment: I done this but not working. i am setting the flash data in my view,

Comment: You **cant set** flash data in view

Comment: in view flash data is generated in session but its shows flash:old so the value is not taking. i changed flash:new manually and its working, actually the code was working for last 1 year.

Comment: No way to do it in view. send data to `controller` and load your same view with `flashdata`

Comment: after set flash data redirect page